# Elasticsearch curl query combining nested, exists, not exists query

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, exists

I cannot figure out how to wrap "query" statements for my query on a complex nested object to work.

I have simplified the concepts to the below -

I have  an index with entries like

```
{
"_index": "my_index",
"_type": "my_type",
"_id": "5",
"_source": {
  "group": "student",
  "user": [
    {
      "first": "Hubert",
      "last": "Rock",
      "grade": "B",
      "address": "12 Hunting St"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

Where 'user' is a nested object. Now I want to conduct a search to identify entries who have a first name 'Hubert',
 but who have no entries in both the 'grade' and 'address' field.

I could do this separately -
(Get all 'Hubert's)

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "user",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "user.first": "Hubert" }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(Get all entries that do not have values for 'grade' and 'address')

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "user",
      "query": {
       "bool": {
          "must_not": [
              {  
                "exists" : {
                  "field":"user.grade"
                  }
              },
              {  
                "exists" : {
                  "field":"user.address"
                  }
              }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I really don't know how to combine them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to combine `must` and `must_not` clause under a single bool query as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "user",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "user.first": "Hubert"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "user.grade"
              }
            },
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "user.address"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```